# mongoose: how query a model with conditions on a property of type reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var UserSchema=new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: 'UserName is required'
        }
    });

var PostingSchema=new Schema({

        creator: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required:true
        }
    });
```

I want to retrieve postings for given username. I am doing in the below way, which is not working.

```
Posting
            .find({ 'creator.username': req.params.username })
            .populate('creator', 'firstName lastName fullName username profile_pic')
            .exec(function(err, postings){
                if (err){
                    res.status(501).json({ error: err});
                } else {
                    res.json(postings);
                }
            });
```

i got empty results array. may be something wrong with the query conditons. how to apply conditions on ref objects. Can someone correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Query populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate)

```
 .populate({ 
      path: 'creator',
      match: { username: req.params.username })
```

Or

```
 .populate('creator', null,  { username: req.params.username })
```